# Compress Block Blob that is already uploaded

Tags: azure, compression, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm working on a project that requires my Block Blob to be copied to another directory inside the same container (directory File to Arquive).

I'm using the method MoveBlobInSameStorageAccount, suggested here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/310a7a6e-efb8-4aef-ba26-7c543fccd443/ssis-script-task-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftwindowsazurestorage-version5000?forum=sqlintegrationservices.

Is it possible to compress the file to a gZip compressed file without having to download it?

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure blobs are not compatible with normal file I/O: You'd need to download the blob locally (stream, file, etc), process it (gzip, in your case), and upload it again. You don't need to download to a local machine; you can download to a VM or any other Azure service where you're running your processing (and if within the same region, you won't have any bandwidth costs).

If you're using Azure Files, then you *can* use normal File I/O, but an Azure File store cannot be used with regular block blobs.